# Chrome Issue with Webfonts & @font-face icons crashing on pages using CAPTCHA

Tags: google-chrome, font-face, captcha, webfonts

First of all I'm relatively new to posting on here so apologies if it isn't quite formatted right.

**The problem:**

Example URL:
http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/finance.php

**What went wrong?**
When refreshing pages with the CAPTCHA plug-in, the @font-face icons would initially disappear upon load, only to be brought back by hovering over them. After another refresh, the problem would then take out Google Web Fonts also.

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Go to: http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/finance.php
2. Page normally loads correctly - notice font-icons used (i.e. by phone numbers).
3. Hit refresh - notice font-icons disappear - hover them to bring back
4. Hit refresh - notice complete fonts disappear - hover to bring back
5. I have isolated problem to CAPTCHA by removing the CAPTCHA from the /finance.php page and problem stops.
6. Similarly, the problem doesn't occur on pages from the same website without CAPTCHA: http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/sellcar.php

**What is the expected behavior?**
Expected Behaviour: When consistently refreshing pages with CAPTCHA plug in, for the Google web-font and @font-face font icons to remain stable on the page.

Does it occur on multiple sites: Yes

Did this work before? Yes I have noticed this fault within the last 24 hours

Does this work in other browsers? Yes

**Further information to help replicate the fault using the example website above: http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/**

Pages with **CAPTCHA** that confirm this problem:

http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/finance.php

http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/partex.php

http://devsite9.clickdealer.co.uk/email.php

All other pages on this website don't contain CAPTCHA and work correctly. Hope this helps.

I have also posted this issue on **Chromium**;
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346653

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds pretty similar to this known Chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c40

Comment: Thanks Megan will have a look